# How to iterate through the list for making a table as below in jsp

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a list of elements.
For this I have

```
   <table>

  <c:forEach items="${dnsList}" var="dnslist">
  <tr>
  <td>dns</td> 
  <td>${dnslist[0]}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>time<td>
   <td>${dnslist[1]}</td></tr>
    <tr>
   <td>msg<td>
   <td>${dnslist[2]}</td></tr>
   </c:forEach>
   <c:forEach items="${connList}" var="connlist">
   <tr>
   <td>conntime</td>
   <td>${connlist[0]}</td></tr>
    <tr>
   <td>uptime</td>
   <td>${connlist[1]}</td></tr>
   </c:forEach>
  </table>
```

but is printing as below

```
     dns       1.23           
     time       98.12           
     msg        OK
     connetion   1.45
     uptime     2.456
```

But I want to display output as( 2 for each loops should iterate and give output as side by side)

```
dns 1.23            connection 1.45
time 98.12           uptime  2.456
msg   OK
```

Please anyone can help me.My list has multiple sub lists in it.So I am iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table> 
<tr>
  <td>dns</td> 
  <td>${dnslist[0]}</td>
   <td>conntime</td>
   <td>${connlist[0]}</td></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>time<td>
   <td>${dnslist[1]}</td>
   <td>uptime</td>
   <td>${connlist[1]}</td></tr>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>msg<td>
   <td>${dnslist[2]}</td></tr>
</table>
```

you are taking elements from index of list then why you are iterating it? If you are iterating it gives correct values if there is only single element in list.Otherwise it will be wrong.

Comment: My list has multiple lists inside it.So i am iterating through it.

Comment: Then don't call the values from list as index[number] . you can put attribute 'varStatus' for indexing. Ok you try post doubts if any errors occoured.